# Не работает jupyter-notebook после добавления библиотек

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Решил я создать окружения через anaconda prompt и загрузить пакет библиотек и после всех манипуляций у меня стала вылезать такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения], на всех окружениях когда я пытаюсь зайти в jupyter-notebook. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой как её решить ?
Что я делал :

1. Откатывать до старой версии полностью anaconda
2. Делал совместимость через свойства с 7й виндой 8й и xp с 3м и 2м пакетами обновлений.
3. Откат jupyter-notebook до 5.7.7

Но результат нулевой , всё так же выходит эта ошибка.
Библиотеки которые я устанавливал:
  -plot
  -seaborn 
  -ggplot

версия jupyter-notebook 5.7.8

Comment: 1. попробуйте запускать Jupyter не из под Anaconda Prompt. 2. запускайте Jupyter используя полный путь созданного VirtualEnv (...\envs\<env_name>\...). Если у вас Windows 10, то не надо настраивать совместимость со старыми версиями

Comment: Полный путь указываю. Но всё равно на версии 5.7.8 не работает . А вот на версии 5.7.6 работает